# How can I select rows from two tables that have slightly different columns? How can I offset them?

Tags: php, mysql, join, inner-join, offset

I’m building a search function for a real estate app and I’m trying to display 100 filtered properties per page.

My SQL for the first load looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE bedrooms = 2 LIMIT 100";
```

Subsequent loads are basically the same with an additional offset. The offset is defined by the page number subtracted by one, multiplied by the properties per page.

```
$page = $_GET[‘page’] - 1;
$propertiesPerPage = 100;
$offset = $page * $propertiesPerPage;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE bedrooms = 2 LIMIT 100 OFFSET ".$offset;
```

This works great. Now I just want to do the same thing, but get properties from two tables instead of just one. I'm trying this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE bedrooms = 2";
$sql .= " UNION ALL ";
$sql .= "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE bedrooms = 2 LIMIT ".$propertiesPerPage." OFFSET ".$offset;
```

However, because each table has a few different columns than the other, I get this error:

`The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns`

Both tables have 60 or more columns but most of the columns are the same. 
Is there a way to select rows from both tables where `WHERE` conditions are met?

Also, how does `OFFSET` work with `JOIN`s? How can I "paginate" the results being selected from two tables?

Comment: you need to supply the column names, you can use alaisis where they dont match up

Comment: If the number of columns do not match, you can't `UNION`, not with `SELECT *`, period.

Comment: Also if the data types dont match you cannot use UNION

Comment: you could do 2 queries and handle all the pagination via php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query needs to be similar to this:

```
$sql = "
SELECT * FROM
(
(SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM table1 WHERE bedrooms = 2)
UNION ALL
(SELECT col1, col2, col3, NULL AS col4 FROM table2 WHERE bedrooms = 2)
) AS myalias
LIMIT ".$propertiesPerPage." OFFSET ".$offset;
```

A couple things:

1. Selected columns listed in corresponding positions of each SELECT statement should have the same data type. (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)
2. Let's say you want it to return all the rows but there are data type mismatches or one table has entirely different columns.  You can still retrieve the data from table1 that has the data but if table2 does not have that column then you would need something like `NULL AS col4`.
3. The reason we use the union as a nested query is because the limit will be applied after both the queries have been joined together.
4. Generally when doing unions you'll be very specific on which columns you'll be fetching.  If you want just 30 columns, you'll need to specify all of those columns in your select queries used for the union.  If it seemed necessary, you could use a PHP variable to define it to reduce the repetition.

Comment: This seems to work so long as I alias the top level SELECT statement. Each table actually has 200+ columns though and I'm having a hard time selecting everything (it's still saying the used SELECT statements have a different number of columns). Is there a way to do this without specifying each column individually? The first table has ~20 columns that the second doesn't and the second table has about ~20 columns that the first doesn't. With over 200 columns to account for, I can't see where the discrepancy lies.

Comment: Ok, I have found the missing column that I wasn't accounting for, and the select now works, however, the values for the second table are in the wrong columns. They seem to be offset by the number of columns that are in the first table but not the second.

Here is a screenshot that demonstrates this.

https://postimg.org/image/9gri1znon/

Comment: You need the selected columns to be in the same matching order that they will be returned as. Share_perc must be in the same spot in each of the subqueries. The order of the selected columns is important so they "line up" when they are unioned

Comment: Ah, ok. That makes sense. Seeing as I have 260+ columns to sort through, I'm starting to think merging these tables into a single table may actually be a better approach. It will just make pagination that much more manageable. That being said, I think you are correct, so I'll set your reply as the answer.

Comment: Will you be displaying all the data from the 260 columns? You can exclude the columns you don't need which would make it more manageable